# NSRegularExpression and NSString comparison

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I want to use `NSRegularExpression` to get some operations done in right order. I have a `NSString`:

```
my_simple_string
```

And I want to call a method (my method, doesn't matter here) like in CSS style so in my `NSDictionary` i have `NSStrings`:

```
*
my*
my_simple*
my_simple_string
```

What i want to do is that my method calls for all this values above. I currently use

```
IsEqualToString
```

and compare every substring. But this is not a perfect solution and when i do my research in web i find a post that suggest use `NSRegularExpression` for it, but i have no idea how can it be helpful.

**One more important thing - "_" is not a separator, I don't have a separator.**

**EDIT:**

```
NSString *str = @"my_simple_string";
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"*",@"my*",@"my_simple*",@"my_simple_string*", nil];

for(int i = 0 ; i < [str length] ; i++) {
    NSString *cut = [str substringToIndex:i];
    cut = [cut stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
    for(int j = 0; j < [arr count] ; j++)
        if([cut isEqualToString:[arr objectAtIndex:j]])
            NSLog(@"find it!");
}

NSLog(@"-----");
```

Comment: Please post the code snippet that you would like to replace with regular expressions. As far as searching through long strings goes, regular expressions are very powerful, so there is a good chance that you'd find them useful too.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated my post with some (simplify) source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a typical regex application. You may find examples on how to use `NSRegularExpression` in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If it's the first time you deal with regexs you'd better check some tutorial on internet (there are plenty of them).